# why what keyword this references in these 2 situation is different?

Tags: javascript

first code

```
var object1 = {name: "my object", 
               ha: function() {
                      return this;
                   }
              }

object1.ha()  #=> Object {name: "my object", ha: function}
```

second code

```
var object2 = {name: "my object2", 
               ha2: function() {
                      return function() {
                               return this;
                             }
                    }
              }

object2.ha()()  #=> window
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `this` in object2 has lost context to the parent object by being placed inside an anonymous function and defaults to being bound to the global object, which, in a browser, is `window`.

You could remedy it by localizing the object reference:

```
var object2 = {
    name : "my object2", 
    ha2  : function() { 
        var _this = this; // <-- here
        return function() { 
            return _this;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` is not a variable it's a keyword whose value is resolved at runtime. It resolves to the nearest bound object creating its scope. This is confusing when you are used to other languages where this is resolved statically. In your example the nearest bound object is window when you run the function.